# Extract text between last occurrence of braces

Tags: python, string, split, partition

I have strings like this,

```
Protein XVZ [Human]
Protein ABC [Mouse]
Protein CDY [Chicken [type1]]
Protein BBC [type 2] [Bacteria]
```

Output should be,

```
Human
Mouse
Chicken [type1]
Bacteria
```

Thus, I want everything inside the last pair of braces. Braces that precede that pair must be ignored as in last example. Is there an effective way to do this in Python? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't last pair of braces for the line `Protein CDY [Chicken [type1]]` be `[type1]`?

Comment: No. Actually, when the last pair falls inside another then I would need the whole thing. Sorry, I was not very clear.

Comment: If you are sure there will always be three columns of data, may be you can use the `csv` module

Comment: Column numbers could be different. My objective is to get the last pair of braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
import re
list = ["Protein XVZ [Human]","Protein ABC [Mouse]","go UDP[3] glucosamine N-acyltransferase [virus1]","Protein CDY [Chicken [type1]]","Protein BBC [type 2] [Bacteria] [cat] [mat]","gi p19-gag protein [2] [Human T-lymphotropic virus 2]"]
pattern = re.compile("\[(.*?)\]$")
for string in list:
    match = re.search(pattern,string)
    lastBracket = re.split("\].*\[",match.group(1))[-1]
    print lastBracket
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It still faces an issue when we have anther brace pair before the last one. For example, >gi p19-gag protein [2] [Human T-lymphotropic virus 2]

Comment: Here. The output should be 'Human T-lymphotropic virus 2'. But it gives '2 Human T lymphotropic virus2'.

Comment: hmmm when I test `gi p19-gag protein [2] [Human T-lymphotropic virus 2]` I get 'Human T-lymphotropic virus 2'. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Actually, I misread it. The case where it does not work is the following:

Comment: >go UDP[3] glucosamine N-acyltransferase [virus1]. Again thanks so much for your time and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It means there could be some text in between where you do the split.

Comment: so I edited my solution. Give that a try and let me know if there are any other instances that give you troubles

Comment: Thank you so very much. I think it works perfect. Will explore further and post again in case there is an issue but it works :) Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help out :). This problem was definitely a fun brainteaser for the night.